Pricing an option on the spread of two contracts, what correlation parameter?
I must price an option on the spread of two futures (A-B) the model I must use uses the IV on the options of each futures. Another parameter I need is the correlation of these, what would be a suitable way to find this please?
Is there a concept of "volatility of the spread"? Could it be done by applying the cosine rule to the IVs and the correlation parameter?
In addition how could this be extended to a cross currency spread i.e. (A*C - B) where C is the adequate currnecy future (or forward)?
Thanks

If you don't care about vega hedging (spread options are not vega hedged typically) then you only need to look at the spread volatility, which you can get as:
(i) historical vol of spread
(ii) specifying correlation historically and using implied vols of A and B, if you believe implied vols are a better representation of realized vols.
Really depends on what you think better approximates realized vol.
For the FX product,
(i) if AC is tradeable and option on AC is tradeable, its the same thing as above.
(ii) If AC is tradeable but an option on AC is not tradeable, you will have to get the vol of the spread historically
(iii) If AC is not tradeable then you need vols of A and C individually (as you need to delta hedge A and C separately now) and thus you will also need vol of B, and the correlation matrix. This will decide the deltas.

The third way (continuing the previous answer) is to get some market or consensus prices of the option on the futures price spread (or prices of basket options, if available) and, given implied vols, imply a correlation level.
For a currency-translated asset, imply a FX rate/asset price correlation from, say, market or consensus quanto forward/options prices (or compo option prices, if available).
